# How to Auto Trigger Button_Click event every 5 sec?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one button name called Submit. I would like to trigger Auto Button_Click event for every 5sec.

**E.g:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Welcome to WPF....");
}
```

Every **5sec** I need to call this `Button_Click` event to show Message like **"Welcome to Google...."** automatically.

Please help me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Wpf`, you could use [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public MainWindow() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 

     Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Timer     
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(); 
    timer.Tick += (s, ev) => btnClickMe.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent)); 
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); 
    timer.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: this method where i need to call.

Comment: public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
   //Timer
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += (s, ev) => btnClickMe.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            timer.Start();
        }

Comment: How to auto trigger this even ?

Comment: I would suggest subscribe for `Loaded` event and then place this logic.

Comment: That will be triggered automatically.

Comment: You don't need to trigger this, every 5 minutes it triggers automatically. If you want you can reduce the span time to see it quickly (ex.. 1 minute or so)

Comment: Great, mark it as an answer if this resolves your problem and is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

create a timer to run every 5 seconds and send: Button_Click(null, null);

```
public static void Main()
{
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Elapsed+= OnTimedEvent;
    timer.Interval=5000;
    timer.Enabled=true;
    Console.ReadKey();
}

 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     Button_Click(null, null);
 }
```

Comment: I tried to add the about code. But i am facing below error:

Comment: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TimerEvent.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' C:\Sample Project\DeSerializeXML\TimerEvent\Form1.cs 32 13 TimerEvent

Comment: remove the static on the timer eg: private void OnTimedEvent

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this. Create a timer of 5 seconds duration and do this on the timer_tick event.

```
buttonName.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```