# Execute button click every 5 seconds until background worker stops to operate and closes

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, buttonclick

I have created a button the calls a SQL table and the user can view the rows of the table. Basically, a query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1
```

and the name of the button is called `View`.

Also, I have created the following background worker that executes a long running query for 4 minutes:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestEnvironment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class ProgressBarTemplate : Window
    {
        private CreateProjectScreen _CreateProjectScreen;
        private LoginScreen _LoginScreen;

        public ProgressBarTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static int RunCalculationsMethod(string connectionstring, string foldername)
        {
            bool exists = Directory.Exists(foldername);

            if (!exists)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(foldername);
            }

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    var calculations_query = "SELECT * FROM table1");

                    using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(calculations_query, sqlConnection);

                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 60 * 10;

                    int NumbderOfRecords = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return NumbderOfRecords;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return -100;
            }
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int IsSuccessful = RunCalculationsMethod("Server=localhost;Database=DB_Name;Integrated Security=SSPI", String.Format("C:\\folder_path\\"));
        }

        void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This is called on the UI thread when the DoWork method completes
            // so it's a good place to hide busy indicators, or put clean up code

            try
            {
                this.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("DQ Calculations completed successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trivial situation here is that the button `View` is on my `MainWindow`, while the code above is on a second window named `ExecuteBGWorker()`.

What I want to achieve is to make a time trigger event to execute the button `View` every 5 seconds until the background worker stops. When the worker stops the button `View` (of the `MainWindow`) will also stop to be auto clicked.

Below is the code of how I call the `ExecuteBGWorker()` method from my `MainWindow`:

```cs
private void View_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The code to execute *View* button;
}

private void CalculationsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    ExecuteBGWorker win_worker = new ExecuteBGWorker();
                    win_worker .Show();
                });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return;
    }
}
```

When I click the View button

[image]

After 5 seconds when clicked again the sql table has more records to show

[image]

I clearly don't have a clue on how to implement this. So please acknowledge my effort to post the question. I have indeed searched about this and I found the DispatcherTimer timer functionality like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739337/how-to-auto-trigger-button-click-event-every-5-sec). However, I am not familiar with C# for a long time so I am not sure how to implement this and make timer to close after the BG_Worker is finished.

Comment: ["Tell Don't Ask"](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) - iow: update the datasource and let wpf do its work.

Comment: @NikSp: Why do you need a window (`ExecuteBGWorker`?) to execute a long-running query? Move the code that performs the query to a method of a class and simply use a `Timer` to call this method once every fifth minute. And what is the difference between `ProgressBarTemplate` and `ExecuteBGWorker`?

Comment: @mm8 Ca you please provide your input for this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211995/performing-button-click-on-ui-window-is-not-sucessfull-through-an-open-thread. I will delete this one because it is obsolete. I have found a work-around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the code that performs the query to a method of a class and simply use a timer to call this method once every fifth minute, e.g.:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
{
    //execute query
};
timer.Interval = 60000 * 5;
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer mm8. I have accepted it since it works as expected.